# Dynamically resizing image Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'd like my image to resize and reposition as I adjust the window size, I've got it to resize and reposition when I adjust the width of the window but when I narrow the height the image doesn't move and starts to run off the screen.

I've read a number of resizing answers on here but can't make sense of them

```
FloatLayout:
        Image:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.6}
            source: 'card.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.45, None
            size: self.texture_size[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width adjustment works because you've set the size_hint to 0.45. This condition is used to automatically update the actual image width when the FloatLayout changes width, and the FloatLayout is the root widget so its width automatically tracks the Window.

In contrast, you have set the vertical size_hint to None. This explicitly means *don't* update the height when the FloatLayout height changes. Try setting this to something like 0.5 instead. If that isn't what you want, ask another question about what you do want.

```
size: self.texture_size[1]
```

This won't work because `size` expects a tuple of (width, height) but `self.texture_size[1]` is a single float value. I think this will actually crash, is this a real example?

You probably meant `height: self.texture_size[1]`, which sets the Image height to the actual height of its displayed image in pixels. But, this clearly isn't what you want, since you want its height to not be fixed and instead scale with the Window.

Comment: Ah thanks, this makes sense now and is working close to what I'd like, I just need to play around with the values of size_hint now. It was meant to me height: self.texture_size[1], a hangover from constant changes but have removed completely now. Thanks